# Invalid header range coming from jwplayer used in android webview

Tags: javascript, android-webview, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using, jwplayer in android webview and when I play videos from player I can see invalid range is coming, so for in valid range I am using following code to server videos in jersey,

```
StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {
@Override
public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException,
WebApplicationException {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
final FileChannel inputChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
final WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output);
try {
inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
} finally {
// closing the channels
inputChannel.close();
outputChannel.close();
}
}
};
MimetypesFileTypeMap typeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mt = typeMap.getContentType(file);
if(fileName.contains(".mp4")) {
mt = "video/mp4";
}
return Response.ok(output, mt).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, file.length()).build();
```

And for valid range, I am using following code to serve videos . . . .

```
final int chunk_size = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks
String[] ranges = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
final int from = Integer.parseInt(ranges[0]);
/**
* Chunk media if the range upper bound is unspecified. Chrome sends "bytes=0-"
*/
int to = chunk_size + from;
if (to >= file.length()) {
to = (int) (file.length() - 1);
}
if (ranges.length == 2) {
to = Integer.parseInt(ranges[1]);
}

final String responseRange = String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", from, to, file.length());
final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
raf.seek(from);

final int len = to - from + 1;
final MediaStreamer streamer = new MediaStreamer(len, raf);
MimetypesFileTypeMap typeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mt = typeMap.getContentType(file);
if(fileName.contains(".mp4")) {
mt = "video/mp4";
}
Response.ResponseBuilder res = Response.ok(streamer, mt).status(206)
.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
.header("Content-Range", responseRange)
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, streamer.getLenth())
.header(HttpHeaders.LAST_MODIFIED, new Date(file.lastModified()));
return res.build();
```

But still I am not able to run videos from android webview, on ios and desktop browsers all videos work fine.
What should I do here . . . . I don't think thats a encoding issue . . . .  This happening for videos uploaded from my android device camera.

Comment: Video page url is: https://app1.zoomvy.com:443/savedVideos-1.0.3.html?deviceId=5de78b92-fe91-2eb3-48f3-d743e4db7352&devicePlatform=desktop&phoneNumber=+14692306470&sessionId=bc0fae024364ce3b2a644ebd583a8a85&mediaItemType=video

Comment: Try to test with this mp4 file to see if it works - http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-364766.mp4

Comment: I have already tested with this url, it works fine with this, why only not for mp4 files from my server and only in android browser, works fine for ios and desktop browsers.

Comment: Then it must be something with your web sever.